# How to close/suspend all open filehandles in a sub-directory tree?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

**Goal**: make file-based operations (rsync) on a directory, without it being changed during that by active processes (httpd)

- A `chmod` on the parent dir or any file **does not** affect already open filehandles
- A reset/kill of the "rogue" writer app is not applicable in this scenario.

Is there a reliable `lsof` one-liner? or any other approach?